# What type of Design is this?

Tags: spss, experiment-design

Participants are asked to recall either a happy or sad event in their life. 
Once a mood of happiness of sadness has been elicited all participants are then presented with 3 stories where the central character was either involved in a happy, sad or neutral event.

The results are as follows:

Happy Story:
Happy- 87, 75, 83
Sad - 55 , 65, 63

Sad Story:
Happy - 85, 78, 68
Sad - 62, 58, 48

Neutral Story:
Happy -    87, 82, 47
Sad -     48, 63, 47

Could someone please tell me what kind of design this is as I have to put it into SPSS and do appropriate tests on it.

Comment: It is quite improper to run an experiment and decide afterwards what design should be used...well what you have above might look like a 2X3 design but it's not...sorry I don't know how the data collection and experiment was run but maybe you can use One way ANOVA. Please give us more details for a better answer (what means 85, 82, ...figures above)